# Proving that doesn't exist subgroup H with order 6 in $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Let $G=A_4$. Prove that does not exist subgroup $H\le G$ s.t $|H|=6$.

I don't know from where to start (maybe I need to prove that if so $H\triangleleft A_4 $?) Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: A subgroup of $A_4$ whose order is a multiple of $6$ must contain a $3$-cycle, and a product of two disjoint $2$-cycles.

Comment: A group of order $6$ contains an element of order $3$: what are the elements of order $3$ in $A_4$? Similarly, a group of order $6$ contains an element of order $2$: what are the elements of order $2$ in $A_4$?

Comment: Notice that the title of your question and the question itself as different questions! (Also, there is *never* any need to abbreviate *such that*)

Comment: So I need to find 3-cycle and product of 2-disjoint-cycles which their product is not in the subgroup? I can't find them...

Comment: Can I say that for example $(34)(134)(124)=(12)\notin A_4$?

Comment: You can say that, @CoarguAliquis...but I can't see how that'll help you prove what you want.

Comment: o.k but can I say that we know type of cycles in $A_4$, if we take their squares they are in $H$ but since we have 8 cycles of 3, that's a contradiction?

Comment: Polishing that argument may help, @CoarguAliquis...but you need the product of an element of order two and one of order three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subgroup of order $\;6\;$ has an element of order three and an element of order two, which then **must** be a $\;3-$cycle and the product of two disjoint $\;2-$cycles (why?). WLOG, suppose that these are

$$(123)\;,\;\;(1i)(jk)\implies (123)(1i)(jk)=\begin{cases}(134)&,\;\;i=2\\{}\\(243)&,\;\;i=3\\{}\\(142)&,\;\;i=4\end{cases}$$

And in any case you already have two different $\;3-$cycles and at least one product of two disjoint transpositions...and this can't be (why? Check you will already have more than 6 elements and thus the subgroup is the whole group $\,A_4\,$)